# VB.NET Simular teclado y mouse

Tags: vb.net

Estoy creando un bot, que utiliza el teclado y el ratón para realizar las acciones, pero lo ideal sería poder hacerlo sin "secuestrar" el pc del usuario.

Que puedo usar como alternativa a sendkeys y mover el puntero del mouse asignándole coordenadas?

Estoy usando esos métodos pero como digo, necesito algo que no capture ni el teclado ni el mouse si no que lo simule o algo por el estilo...

Es decir que si el programa está en segundo plano poder enviarle órdenes igualmente y que el usuario pueda seguir trabajando sin interrupción.

Saludos y muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes usar `sendkeys` para enviar pulsaciones a otro proceso en segundo plano, mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292428/579895). Lo del ratón diría que no es posible, aunque tal vez pudieras simular la pulsación de botones...pero nunca lo hice,asi que no te lo aseguraría.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de hacer "bump" aquí sin que me resten puntos?

Comment: Claro. Edita tu pregunta añadiendo mucha mas información, y de esa manera subirá y si la pregunta es buena no creo que te voten negativamente.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a la [clase Cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.position?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Cursor_Position)